# Is WCF RoutingService transactional?

Tags: .net, wcf, routes, transactions, msmq

In WCF4 we a provided with a great feature - routing services. MSMQ4 supports remote transactional read. So now building simple publish-subscribe on WCF seems to be a piece of cake. But I get one doubt. Does the System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService, which implements routing stuff for messages, work in a transactional manner with MSMQ? From the MSDN documentation it's not obvious.

Here is how I build a router, which is considered to be a publisher. I declare a routing service, add an msmq input endpoint. Subscribers also have msmq input endpoint. I configure client endpoints on the router, add filters. What will happen if by some accident the router service fails? For instance, some custom filter fails. Will the message return to the input queue?

Comment: If you have solved this please write your own answer, I have the same problem.

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN, yes, WCF Routing Service can be configured to use transactions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667251.aspx

The link discusses an example in the wcf samples pack, under advanced error handling